# Regular expressions - unmatch if inside braces

Tags: javascript, python, regex

I'm trying to parse a javascript file to get all the files required with the `require` function, but I want to be sure those requires aren't inside an enclosing bloc

To simply parse `require` calls, this is what I did

```
regex = re.compile(
    r"require\([\'\"](?P<filename>\.{1,2}.*?)(?:\.jsx?)?[\'\"]\)",
    re.M | re.I)
```

So how to discard `require`'s in blocks? For example, if I had:

```
var test = require("./test");
{
  var test2 = require("./test2");
}
```

I would get `./test` but not `./test2`

I could naively try to unmatch `require`'s with an opening brace before, but my regex doesn't seem to work, it still matches the ones I don't want

```
(?<!{)[^{]*?require\([\'\"](?P<filename>\.{1,2}.*?)(?:\.jsx?)?[\'\"]\)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you insist this to be done with just regex. Isn't impossible, it is just guaranteed to be unreadable.

Comment: yes -.- if possible. this is the only parsing I need to do, I don't think using a parsing library is worth it haha

Comment: I didn't mean a parsing library, just counting the number of `{` and `}` in a loop.

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest *not* trying to do that with regex. It is going to be a huge headache for you. Instead process the file with the KISS principle in mind:

```
depth = 0 #To count nested blocks
word = "" #To keep track of the code we find before delving into another block
resultString = "" #To keep track of all code in the outermost block
inputJS = "var test = require(\"./test\");\n{\nvar test2 = require(\"./test2\");\n}\n" #input string
for i in inputJS: #Loop through one letter at a time
    if i == "{": #If it is an opening brace then increase depth
        resultString += word
        depth += 1
        word = ""
    elif i == "}": #If it is a closing brace decrease depth
        depth-=1
    elif depth == 0: #If we are at the top scope then keep track of the character
        word += i

#Parse resultString Normally
```

NOTE: This is *not* a general block parsing algorithm (as you can probably tell). This is meant only to pick up words that are not in a block. Also note that I have assumed the braces are balanced.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you insisted, I created a regex to do the job:

Ruby version ([in action](http://rubular.com/r/v5MhWAII7R)):

```
/(?<balanced_brackets>(?<no_brackets>[^{}]*)|\g<no_brackets>(?:\{\g<balanced_brackets>\}\g<no_brackets>)+){0}require\((?:"[^"]+"|'[^']+')\)(?!\g<balanced_brackets>}\g<balanced_brackets>\z)/x
```

As you can see, this is completely unreadable. You should instead be looping through the code and keep count of the opening(`{`) and closing(`}`) brackets and accept a match only if it was preceded by an equal number of the two.

Comment: The downfall to the method in my answer and the method you suggest here is if there are any commented braces/braces that appear in strings in the code.

Comment: And also whether you are in a string or not. Though I believe the same problem arises with regex's anyway.

Comment: What was the issue with the python version?

Comment: I wasn't sure how to translate part of the syntax from ruby to python and couldn't find which part (as the regex is unreadable). The solution wasn't the point of my answer - the point was - don't do this with regex.